# Exception to derive from something I am already deriving from For RoleManager<TRole>

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

## Question information

use case: i am trying to use ApplicationRoleManager in my constructor for a asp net 5 controller. My ApplicationRoleManager is basically concrete implementation of     public class RoleManager : IDisposable where TRole : class

Can somebody show me some example code of how to use   //.AddRoleManager() instead of my work around.

Technology: Asp Net 5 
Exception: Exception: Additional information: Type ApplicationRoleManager must 
derive from RoleManager.

## In my Startup.cs

```
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>()
                //EXCEPTION OCCURS only when I try to AddRolemanager
                .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
                .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

## My Model

```
 public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string>
    {
        public ApplicationRole()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public ApplicationRole(string name)
           : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Predictably I try to use RoleManager where Application role derives from identity

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(
            IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>store, 
            IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>> roleValidators,
            ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
            ILogger<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>  logger,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor
            )
           :base(
                    store:store,
                    roleValidators: roleValidators, 
                    keyNormalizer: keyNormalizer,
                    errors:errors,
                    contextAccessor: contextAccessor,
                    logger: logger)
        {
        }

    }
```

### My work around

I managed to get the dependency in my controller working as shown below but my goal is to learn how to use  .AddRoleManager

```
   public GroupsAdminController(ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
```

{
     //so now if i add the services.AddScoped etc... on the start up it doesnt //throw an error. 
 }

```
 services.AddScoped<ApplicationRoleManager, ApplicationRoleManager>();
services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
 services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed 
 `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()`

to

`services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()`

after noticing there was a type mismacth ApplicationRoleManager !